# Trim pathname in CSV file

Tags: awk, sed, csv, columns, filter

I am struggling over a filter where I am trying to trim data in a specific column of a CSV after the 3rd or nth occurrence of the character `\`.

My data looks something like this:

```
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\folder4\...,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\folder4\...,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\folder4\...,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\folder4\...,data,data,data
```

I want the filter to produce:

```
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
```

The 3rd column contains a file path, and it may be anywhere from one folder to many. I want there to be a maximum of 3 folders.

I don't want to delete the other remaining columns but edit the file in place.

I've been experimenting with `awk`, `sed`, and trying to combine the `cut` command `cut -f1-4 -d '\'` into an `awk` statement but cannot for the life of me get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F "\\" '{gsub(/\.*,/,",",$0);print $1"\\"$2"\\"$3"\\"$4$NF}' file.txt

data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data,data
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
qw=re.compile(r'\.*')
k=open('file.txt','r')
for i in k:
    respa=re.sub(qw,"",i.strip()).strip().split('\\')
    print "{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}{4}".format(respa[0],respa[1],respa[2],respa[3],respa[-1])
```

output

```
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data,data
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen these solutions work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=gensub("(([^\\\\]*\\\\){"n+1"}).*","\\1",1,$3)} 1' file
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} match($3,"(([^\\\\]*\\\\){"n+1"})"){$3=substr($3,1,RLENGTH)} 1' file
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
```

Comment: Thank you Ed you are amazing.. you are a life saver... may Zeus bless the with riches and immortality.. hehe. Have an awesome day!

Comment: You're welcome, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk for what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, assuming no other earlier field contains strings delimited by four backslashes:

```bsh
$ sed 's/\(\([^,\]\{1,\}[\]\)\{4\}\)[^,]*/\1/' file
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
```

Or, using an extended regular expression,

```bsh
$ sed -E 's/(([^,\]+[\]){4})[^,]*/\1/' file
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3\,data,data,data
```

The `sed` expression used here is a substitution, and the text being substituted is whatever matches `(([^,\]+[\]){4})[^,]*`.  This regular expression matches and captures four non-empty backslash-delimited strings (`([^,\]+[\]){4}`). This is captured for re-use in the replacement string, but everything up to and including the next comma (whatever is matched by the trailing `[^,]*`) is discarded.

The replacement text is `\1`, which inserts those four bits of backslash-delimited strings.

---

You could obviously also do this with `cut` and `paste` but note that the below command pipeline reads the file *three times*, and also drops the final backslash on the pathnames in the 3rd field:

```bsh
$ paste -d , <( cut -d , -f -2 file ) <( cut -d , -f 3 file | cut -d '\' -f -4 ) <( cut -d , -f 5- file )
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data
```

You could get rid of the first `cut` by treating the first two fields as part of the pathname in the 3rd field though, but this still reads the file twice:

```bsh
$ paste -d , <( cut -d '\' -f -4 file ) <( cut -d , -f 5- file )
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data
data,data,c:\path1\folder2\folder3,data,data
```